# Chrome app extension with flash not loading

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extension

I recently tried to create an app for chrome which needs to load some flash player.

Unfortunately after finishing everything, I recevied an error message saying Adobe Flash Player is not Allowed.

For more info here's the image:
[image]

My chrome loads the flash player properly when manually added.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Here's what you need to do to fix it:

1. Type chrome://settings in the address bar.
2. Click on Show advanced settings
3. Under Privacy click on Content Settings
4. Ensure Plug-ins are set to Run Automatically. Click on Done.

If you still need help check this guide with screenshots - [Fix Adobe Flash Player is Not Allowed error in Google Chrome](http://www.fixnowsupport.com/3/post/2013/09/fix-adobe-flash-player-is-not-allowed-in-google-chrome.html)